# Django login page via /accounts/login/ instead of /

Tags: django, authentication, system

I have just begun using Django and after a long time struggling I finally made the login work. The only problem is that I have to go to ip_address/accounts/login/ to login. I want to have this as the first thing you see, so on the link: ip_address/

I was wondering if there is such a thing like LOGIN_URL for the homepage or another solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest a slightly different approach. Leave your login page as it is, and use the `login_required` decorator on your homepage. When users first come to your site, they will be redirected to your login page to log in, then redirected back to your homepage afterwards.

myapp/views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'homepage.html', {})
```

Project's urls.py:

```
from myapp.views import home

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),
    ...
]
```

Comment: and this urls.py is also in my app I guess?

Comment: No, that's your main `urls.py`. You could put it in your app's `urls.py` if you include it with `path('', include('myapp.urls)`. If you have `path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls)` then you're defining a URL for `/myapp/`, which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your root url.py file, add the following code:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
]
```

you can edit the url() function to match the link you want to put on your login page.

Comment: I now have: path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')), do I have to replace it with this code? (I know that instead of the url(r'^/$') I am now using the path()

Comment: You are using django2.0 instead of django1.11, but basically it's almost the same. Just using: path('/', auth_views.login) instead of url function.See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions for details.

Comment: @zhiqianghuang - you don't need the slash, it should be `url(r'^$', ...)` and `path('', ...)`.

Comment: Yeah, because by default django automatic append slash in the end(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#append-slash), I personally prefer to put the slash in the end to clarify myself.

Comment: The problem was that I also got another (not working) login url in the my app/urls.py. This blocked the good one. Now it works. Thanks for your help

Comment: No, `APPEND_SLASH` is something different. If you include the slash in  `url(r'^/$', ...)` and `path('/', ...)` then you are defining URLs for `example.com//` instead of `example.com/`.